# OneDrive Won't Upgrade, Stuck at "Resuming.."

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I've tried the troubleshooter.
I've tried skydrive.exe /reset (same as troubleshooter).
I've tried installing the latest version of OneDrive directly over.
I've tried relocating the directory.

Nothing works and the version remains at 6.3.9600.17484 while the latest version is 17.3.xxx...

[image]

[image]

I am willing to try any solution except reformatting my computer.

Comment: this is fine, the 17.x version only works with Win7/8.

Comment: Yeah it is both Windows 8.1.

Comment: in 8.1, OneDrive integrated directly into Windows so you can't use the normal setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to inform you that since OneDrive is a built in feature in Windows 8.1 you cannot uninstall it, however you can disable all of the syncing features.

I suggest you to convert the Microsoft account to Local account and then back to Microsoft account. Configure OneDrive  and check if the issue persists.

Refer to these steps to change Microsoft Account into Local User Account:

a. Press Windows and I keys together.

b. Click on Settings, then click on Change PC Settings.

c. Click on Account.

d. On Your account page, under the User name and User ID, you will be able to see “Disconnect” option.

e. Click on Disconnect and follow the on-line instructions.

Refer to these steps to convert Local User Account into Microsoft Account:

a. Press Windows and I keys together.

b. Click on Settings, then click on Change PC Settings.

c. Click on Account.

d. Click on Connect to Microsoft Account and follow the online instructions.

Now try accessing OneDrive and check if it helps

Keep us posted on the issue to assist you better.